# Comparing UTC with local in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a date column called `actual_cargo_ready_date_local`, it is of type `TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)`.
Next we're trying to compare a column with UTC values, say the column name is `booked_at`.

Is it correct to do the comparison as follows;

`booked_at > actual_cargo_ready_date_local::timestamp_ntz`

Essentially, my question is can we compare a column with values in UTC with timestamp column with values in local timezone.
And is it true that using the command `actual_cargo_ready_date_local::timestamp_ntz` coverts the `actual_cargo_ready_date_local` into UTC.
Thanks

Comment: Is `actual_cargo_ready_date_local` really local time? If so, it's going to be a bit of a challenge because it's defined as `TIMESTAMP_NTZ`. If your local timezone offset changes due to daylight savings time, you need to adjust for that. Also on the night the clocks roll back an hour, there are ambiguous times. For example, on that night there are two 2:30am times, not one. Each 2:30am has its own offset from UTC, but a `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` doesn't capture that. If you're using local time and your local time adjusts for DST, you should consider using `TIMEZONE_TZ`.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Use [`CONVERT_TIMEZONE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html).

If `actual_cargo_ready_date_local` and `booked_at` are both of type `TIMESTAMP_NTZ`, there is no notion of the "origin" timezone here at all, so the system can not automatically make the comparisons right.

Casting `actual_cargo_ready_date_local::timestamp_ntz` does not have any effect, as the datatype doesn't change.

However, if you know that `actual_cargo_ready_date_local` is in some timezone, let's say `America/New_York`, and `booked_at` is in `UTC`, you can use [`CONVERT_TIMEZONE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) to convert the times into `UTC`:

```
booked_at > CONVERT_TIMEZONE(actual_cargo_ready_date_local, 'America/New_York', 'UTC')
```